# Does IE10 not support canvas drawImage() alpha blending? (jsfiddle example)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, transparency

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g3fT/).  I am first painting a red background, then painting green stripes on top of this image.  The gaps between the green stripes are set with an alpha of 0.  In all browsers other than IE, the resulting image looks like this:

[image]

In IE, however, it looks like this:

[image]

There doesn't appear to be any support for blending, even in a simple case of alpha=0.  Is there something I'm missing?  Do I need to blend the colors myself in order to have this work in IE?  Can anyone explain what's happening here?  Here is the code from the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8g3fT/)...

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var finalCanvas, finalCanvasCtx, size, drawCanvas, drawCanvasCtx, drawImageData, ctrV, ctrH, ctrVStep, ctrHStep, index;

// final canvas
finalCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
finalCanvasCtx = finalCanvas.getContext("2d");
size = finalCanvas.width;

// drawing canvas
drawCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
drawCanvas.width = size;
drawCanvas.height = size;
drawCanvasCtx = drawCanvas.getContext("2d");
drawImageData = drawCanvasCtx.createImageData(size, size);

// draw red background
for (ctrV = 0; ctrV < size; ctrV++) {
    for (ctrH = 0; ctrH < size; ctrH++) {
        var index = ((ctrV * size) + ctrH) * 4;
        drawImageData.data[index] = 255;
        drawImageData.data[index+1] = 0;
        drawImageData.data[index+2] = 0;
        drawImageData.data[index+3] = 255;
    }
}

// paint red background to final canvas
drawCanvasCtx.putImageData(drawImageData, 0, 0);
finalCanvasCtx.drawImage(drawCanvas, 0, 0);

// draw green overlay
for (ctrV = 0; ctrV < size; ctrV++) {
    for (ctrH = 0; ctrH < size; ctrH++) {
        ctrVStep = Math.round(ctrV / 10);
        ctrHStep = Math.round(ctrH / 10);

        index = ((ctrV * size) + ctrH) * 4;
        drawImageData.data[index] = 0;
        drawImageData.data[index+1] = 255;
        drawImageData.data[index+2] = 0;

        if ((ctrVStep % 2) == 0) {
            drawImageData.data[index+3] = 255;
        } else {
            drawImageData.data[index+3] = 0;
        }
    }
}

// draw green overlay to final canvas
drawCanvasCtx.putImageData(drawImageData, 0, 0);
finalCanvasCtx.drawImage(drawCanvas, 0, 0);
```

Comment: `drawImage` is basic.. supported from IE9 onwards.. but it seems even IE11 doesnt support canvas blending...   http://caniuse.com/canvas-blending ._.

Comment: @PsychHalf Thanks, I guess it's just not supported in IE.  (That chart indicates it's not supported in Safari 6, although it does indeed work there.)

Comment: no probs.. yeah.. i guess you have to either screw ie.. or use a shim or something like that.. or just wait for when ie supports it.. (well.. maybe when they tested it.. it wasnt supported in the build which they tested.... who knows..)

Answer (score 1):

Check out canvas's `context.globalCompositeOperation`

Compositing has many features, but for your needs it does this:

Drawing new drawing under existing drawings (new drawings fill only transparent areas of the existing canvas)

It's supported in IE9+.

[image]

Here is sample code:

```
ctx.fillStyle="green";
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    ctx.fillRect(0,i*20,canvas.width,10);
}
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,200);
```